# Is there any Lightning Container Component for the Lightning Web Components framework?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, lightning-container

I am about to kick start a project that's gonna make use of the [Lightning Container](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:container) in the Lightning Aura Framework.

**Q:** Is there any LWC counterpart for this aura component?

From the documentation it seems not to address anything similar.

Interest to know this because I would like to make a decision and test out both approaches, and probably opt for the Lightning Web Component framework, as it seems the forward-looking technology endorsed by Salesforce.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Currently, you do not have LWC alternative to lightning:container.

Whenever you need to check similar tags for Aura vs LWC, you can check this [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.migrate_map_aura_lwc_components).

However, once check [lwc:dom directive](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/reference_directives). Your requirement may fulfil with `lwc:dom`

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Wasn't aware of that comparison overview.

Well, not sure how much that would apply to my case cause we're about to host(potentially multiple) React components in a Lightning Community UI. From a 1st glance couldn't see how lwc:dom directive would help me.

Comment: You cannot host the application in lwc:dom. But again, when you are implementing whole application in React, it does not matter whether its Aura or LWC. You can use Aura to host and use that Aura anywhere in lightning. For all other custom development you can maintain LWC comp which is sibling of lightning:container in Aura comp. Hope it makes sense

Comment: If I understood it correctly you're suggesting to have the React App, wrapped in the Lightning Aura Component via the lightning:container component, and this aura component wrapped in an LWC component?

Comment: No, you can only add LWC component within Aura, not Aura inside LWC. You can have Aura cmp with lightning:container, for other LWC and so, you can wrap inside Aura or inside Lightning Page.